# how is the calculation of rgb values done in the dialog "windows color and appearance"

Tags: windows-7, colors, windows-xp, rgb

In Windows 7 and Windows XP you can find the "Window Color and Appearance" dialog under "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization".
Changing "Color1" of item "3D-Border" will result in a change of the following entries in the registry key

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors]

containing the resulting rgb-values:

Group1 (same values):

> InactiveTitle, AppWorkspace, ButtonShadow, Graytext

Group2 (same values, different to those of group1):

> Scrollbar, ButtonHilight

Does anyone know how these value are being calculated from the given rgb-values of "Color1"? 
After searching the web without results and playing around with many values I did not happen to find a plausible way of how to do this.
Does anyone know the rules for this?
Any help would be appreciated.

I uploaded some [demo values](http://www.scribd.com/doc/158225900/WindowColorAndAppearance-xlsx?secret_password=1k8pqr803t4hdkh0yvx8), systematically dealing with values in the lower parts. Also a [text file](http://www.scribd.com/doc/158224460/3D-Objects-registry-before-after-txt?secret_password=tq0y95bs0xnzy25yuwt) comparing the affected registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors] after change of Color to Red (255 0 0).

Comment: There must be some kind of numerical relation. Can you give a number of examples of 'before-after' pairs? It's either an RGB space addition or multiplication, or simply a higher or lower brightness in HSB space.

Comment: @Jongware: Maybe I do not see the wood for the trees, I am not all familiar with dealing with rgb values in particular. I uploaded some of my researched data

Answer (score 0):

When you set the "3D Border" color to red, it changed the "Button Face" color to red and interpolated this color to generate various lighter and darker shades of red, which were used to set some related color values.

The point is to create a consistent-looking theme with minimal effort. All you need to do is set the "base" color for 3D objects, and all of the other colors are automatically calculated to ensure that objects have the appropriate 3D appearance.

Some of these values, like the highlight and shadow colors used for 3D objects, are not directly configurable from the control panel applet. However, they can be set manually in the registry, and you can call the `SetSysColors` function to update currently running applications.

Why do you think you need to know the actual algorithm that Windows is using? What problem are you trying to solve? What are you going to use this information to do?

I do not imagine that the exact algorithm is documented anywhere. The code has been part of the OS since at least Windows 95.

Comment: Well, playing around with and researching the capabilites of that "Window Color and Appearance" dialog I was not expecting coming across a windows internal secret, I was focussing rather on the mathematical context than on understanding the meaning of creating that whole theme. thank you, Cody Gray.